# In Parse() function, why the time.ANSIC layout didn't work in Go?

Tags: go

I am currently studying time library and I am not sure why the time.ANSIC at layout part didn't work what I expected.
In Parse() function there is a syntax  `func Parse (layout, value string)` and based on my understanding I can use in layout part like time.UnixDate, ANSIC, RFC3339 etc.

When I code like below

```
const layout = "Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm (MST)"
    sm, _ := time.Parse(layout, "Feb 4, 2014 at 6:05pm (PST)")
    fmt.Println(sm)
```

It works as well and I got 2014-02-04 18:05:00 +0000 PST.

However, when I add time.ANSIC at layout part

```
tm, _ := time.Parse(time.ANSIC, "Feb 4, 2014 at 6:05pm (PST)")
    fmt.Println(tm)
```

I got 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC.

I am not sure why do I get any time. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You shouldn't discard errors from the Parse function. It should show you `parsing time "Feb 4, 2014 at 6:05pm (PST)" as "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006": cannot parse "Feb 4, 2014 at 6:05pm (PST)" as "Mon"`

Comment: The layout that works for you does not equal to `time.ANSIC`. Why do you expect it to work?

Comment: @Inian when I run the code, I didn't see any error message! I only got 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

Comment: @icza Oh I see! However, when I tried to time.ANSIC format such as “Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006”. I got the same result.

Comment: @JiwanJeon94 Because you are ignoring the second argument completely by `_`. See my answer and playground example

Comment: @Inian yeah you`re right! I also check the error message and figure it out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not idiomatic Go to discard errors returned from any of the methods in standard library. Always check them before processing your returned value.

If you had noticed the error from your parse function, you would see that the layout for `time.ANSIC` is not compatible with the date string that you are trying to parse

> parsing time "Feb 4, 2014 at 6:05pm (PST)" as "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006": cannot parse "Feb 4, 2014 at 6:05pm (PST)" as "Mon"

From https://pkg.go.dev/time#Parse

> The second argument must be parseable using the format string (layout) provided as the first argument.

https://go.dev/play/p/jU-EvL5W3Hp

Comment: I really appreciate it :)